# How do I access the title of my WP7 app for labelling a pivot control?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, pivot, title

At the start of the pivot control on my main page, there is a space to enter the title of my application:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
```

What can I put in here so that it uses the value from the WMAppManifest file? (as shown below)

```
<App xmlns="" ProductID="{xxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxx}" Title="The Title" RuntimeType="Silverlight" ... >
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PhoneHelper class from the [coding4fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/). [This article](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Getting-data-out-of-WP7-WMAppManifest-is-easy-with-Coding4Fun-PhoneHelper) describes how to use it.

In XAML:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="{Binding AppTitle}">
```

In your page class:

```
public string AppTitle
{
  get { return PhoneHelper.GetAppAttribute("Title"); }
}
```

Note: I haven't actually tested the code above but it should work as is, or with minor modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can always parse the WMAppManifest.xml file to get the `Title`. Description of this method is available [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/01/04/get-application-title-from-windows-phone.aspx).